# How can I build a filter that contains a certain text by gas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a script that works fine

```
function setFilter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var filterSettings = {};
  filterSettings.range = {sheetId: ss.getSheetByName("mySheet").getSheetId()};
  filterSettings.criteria = {};
  filterSettings['criteria'][4] = {
    'hiddenValues': ["FALSE"]
  };
  var request = {
    "setBasicFilter": {
      "filter": filterSettings
    }
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());
}
```

with in column E

```
={"test";arrayformula(if(B2:B="",,not(iserror(find("mike",B2:B)))))}
```

- I would like to replace hiddenValues FLASE on column E (4) by when text contains "something" in column B (1), I tried `'textContains': ['mike']` but that doesn't work
- Is it possible to create a filterview instead of a basic filter

Comment: I think that your 2nd question of `Is it possible to create a filterview instead of a basic filter Here is my spreadsheet` can be achieved. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your 1st question of `I would like to replace hiddenValues FLASE on column E (4) by when text contains "something" in column B (1), I tried 'textContains': ['mike'] but that doesn't work`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike : for the first question, Iamblichus gave a solution, thanks. If you can help me with the second one, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your 1st question, I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your 2nd question, I commented on the answer and the thread including the sample script to the Iamblichus's answer. Could you please confirm it? I thought that in this case, when the answer to the 2nd question is included in the Iamblichus's answer, it will be more useful.

Comment: @Tanaike, everything is fine! thank you so much for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issues were resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You have to define `TEXT_CONTAINS` under field `condition`.

#### Solution:

Replace this:

```
filterSettings['criteria'][4] = {
  'hiddenValues': ["FALSE"]
};
```

With this:

```
filterSettings['criteria'][1] = {
  "condition": {
    "type": "TEXT_CONTAINS",
    "values": [
      {
        "userEnteredValue": "mike"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

#### Notes:

- `criteria` is deprecated, consider using [filterSpecs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#FilterSpec) instead.
- I didn't notice your second question before. Take a look at [Managing filter views](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters#managing_filter_views) for information on creating filter views.

#### Reference:

- [BasicFilter](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#basicfilter)
- [BooleanCondition](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#BooleanCondition)
- [ConditionType](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#conditiontype)

Comment: Although unfortunately, I cannot understand OP's 1st question, about OP's 2nd question for adding the filter view, this sample script might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70779205/7108653 In order to convert the request body for putting the basic filter to that for putting the filter view, please replace `setBasicFilter` with `addFilterView`. By this, other properties can be used without modification. In this case, I thought that when this information is added to your answer, your answer might be more useful.

Comment: @Iamblichus thank you very much for this answer... and for the second question, I know the url and I tried to work with it, nevertheless I don't really understand how to give a number to "filterViewId", maybe a randomize?

Comment: @Mike Steelson About `filterViewId`, when this property is not used, it is automatically added. When `filterViewId` is included, you can set freely the value and use it for another request in the batch request. So it is not required to use `filterViewId` if you are not required to set the specific value. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70779205/7108653)

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, I will now take a look at your other sample script which I couldn't find before. I'll get back to you if I need any further help. Thank you very much for both.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an already existing filter on the spreadsheet.
Grab the existing filter and use the filter criteria builder.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder#whenTextContains(String)

```
const sheet = activeRange.getSheet();
const filter = sheet.getFilter();
const criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenTextContains('mike')
  .build();

// The "3" below says put the filter in the 4th column of the filter. 
filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(3, criteria);

/* to reset the filter at that column.
  filter.removeColumnFilterCriteria(3)
*/
```